# Data Won't Save To Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0wSh.png)

Hi! So I've been trying to make a basic note app and I've run into a wall. I've spent hours trying to get my data to save to my sharedPreferences, but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work. I've added logs to the app so we can examine what is happening.

LOGS:

02-22 18:27:56.767 4929-4929/com.example.jackson.collegeplanner I/TEST: notesSet didn't return null!

(When I click the addnote button)

02-22 18:29:54.500 4929-4929/com.example.jackson.collegeplanner I/TEST: newNote added to notesSet

Code:

```
public class Schedule extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    //        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this .getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SharedPreferences myPref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Set<String> notesSet = myPref.getStringSet("NN", null);

        if(notesSet != null){
            notes.addAll(notesSet);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            Log.i("TEST", "notesSet didn't return null!");
        }
        else{
            notesSet = new HashSet<String>();
            notesSet.add("Ya note's set is empty");
            notes.addAll(notesSet);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            Log.i("TEST", "noteSet returned null");
        }

        myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();

    }

    public void AddNote(View view){
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String newNote = editText.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences myPref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.jackson.collegeplanner", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> notesSet = myPref.getStringSet("NN", null);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        notesSet.add(newNote);
        Log.i("TEST", "newNote added to notesSet");
        notes.clear();
        notes.addAll(notesSet);

        editText.setText("");

        myPref.edit().putStringSet("NN", notesSet).apply();

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem that you are suffering? The image show the true result

Comment: I'm trying to make sure my data saves after I hit the plus. For some reason it doesn't save when I exit out of the app, kill it, and reopen it. So when it reloads I only ever get those two items.

Comment: the second item that you've inserted, right?

Comment: I didn't insert it via the editText. In old code, (I've been trying to get this to work for a few hours) I had inserted the line into the code via programming, but I haven't been able to save anything via the + and load it up on the next onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is from a duplicate post I made and it was answered there.

Oh, I just remembered a catch with String Sets in SharedPreferences that you're probably coming up against. (I admit I didn't really test your code very thoroughly when I did it.) You cannot try to modify the Set you get from `getStringSet()` and then save it back. You need to instantiate a new one, and pass that to `putStringSet()`. In your code, a simple fix would be: `Set<String> notesSet = new HashSet<String>(myPref.getStringSet("NN", null));`. **– Mike M.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 if(myPref.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).commit())
    Log.d(TAG , "SAVED");
 else 
    Log.d(TAG , "Not Saved");
```

To check if shared preferences were actually saved.

Answer (score 0):

in your code change

```
 `
if(set == null){
    set = new HashSet<String>();
    notes.add("Initial Notes");
    set.addAll(notes);
}
`
```

to

```
`
if(set == null){
    set = new HashSet<String>();
    notes.add("Initial Notes");
    set.addAll(notes);
    myPref.edit().putStringSet(set).apply();
}
`
```